# React-native-webview in expo ios automatically opens url that don't match originWhitelist

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-webview

I am using Expo to build an app that serves a website using `react-native-webview`. It's working in android, but however in iOS with custom `originWhitelist`, `react-native-webview` automatically opens custom scripts in Safari without any user interaction.

For example:

```
<WebView
  source={{
     uri: 'https://www.bbc.com',
  }}
  originWhitelist={['https://*bbc.com']}
/>
```

On load, the webview opens a link that doesn't fit the whitelist automatically. You can check the screen cap here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/jjRp8.jpg. In addition to that, it also shows other urls that can't be opened (My guess is that because the app isn't on foreground). Here's one of the error messages from the console:
[image]

Environment:

**OS**: iOS
**OS** version: 13.5.
**react-native version**: React Native 0.62.2 for Expo SDK38.
**react-native-webview version**: ^9.4.0.